# Android Get names and coordinates of all places (similar to google places)

Tags: android, geolocation, maps, geocoding

I am working on an application which displays all the hospitals,coffee bars on a map, near to the user in android. Any idea how to get these details. Something similar to google places application. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I have actually the same problem to search and display information on my ViewMap. Actually I have tried to used te Googles Places API. In oreder to use it, you must have an AdSense id and fill a form to appli that you can find at http://gmaps-ws-console.appspot.com/, but if it works for u, you're a lucky man and I beg you to let me know how you did it.

So to get information, actually I use this URL. http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=1+Place+Delille,+Clermont+Ferrand,+France&output=xml&oe=utf8\ and there you can get the xml information that you can use in your App Android like these...

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();   
String result = "";
ResponseHandler<String> handler = new BasicResponseHandler();   
byte[] utf8s;
        utf8s = txtSearch.getText().toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
        String place = new String(utf8s, "UTF-8"); 
        place = place.trim().replace(" ", "+");

        HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q="+place+"&output=xml&oe=utf8");

    result = httpclient.execute(request, handler);
    String coordonees = result.substring(result.indexOf("<coordinates>"), result.indexOf("</coordinates>"));
```

you can get the coordinates and the let your viewmap show your place via:

> mapController.setCenter(new
>   GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1E6), (int) (lng
>   * 1E6)));

Hope it works for u... It lets me find public places, but not specific places...

Comment: thanks for info. I will inform you if I get more info. I will try this now.